# IConfiguration doesn't contain AppSettings

Tags: c#, .net-core

In my API I have in the Startup.cs this constructor:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                                    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                                    .AddEnvironmentVariables();      
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

Debugging and/or trying to get here a value from appsettings.json works.

In my controller, I can't get a value, it's always null. When debugging, there's no AppSettings-section in the configuration.

This is my controller-constructor:

```
public ImageController(IImageRepository imageRepository, IMapper mapper, ITagRepository tagRepository, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _configuration = configuration;

    _imageRepository = imageRepository;
    _tagRepository = tagRepository;
    _mapper = mapper;

    var c = _configuration["AppSettings:ImagesPath"];
}
```

and `c` here is always null.

This is my appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AppSettings": {
    "ImagesPath": "/Users/username/temp/skp/"
  }
}
```

When debugging, there are no AppSettings-keys in it
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Startup.cs, ConfigureServices method, can you check if you have:

```
 services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
```

then in your controller:

```
_configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:ImagesPath");
```

if this fails, try:

```
var imagesPath = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:ImagesPath");

then use .Value to get the actual value
```

Comment: That was the problem. I had an AddTransient with provider => Configuration - now it works. (Do not really know why I had this :D) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Injecting `IConfiguration` is usually not advised.

Instead, create a strong type to bind the desired settings

```
public class AppSettings {
    public string ImagesPath { get; set; }
}
```

and configure it in startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    //...omitted for brevity

    AppSettings settings = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(AppSettings)).Get<AppSettings>();
    services.AddSingleton(settings);

    //...
}
```

The controller can now be refactored to expected the strongly typed settings

```
public ImageController(IImageRepository imageRepository, IMapper mapper, 
    ITagRepository tagRepository, AppSettings settings) {

    _imageRepository = imageRepository;
    _tagRepository = tagRepository;
    _mapper = mapper;

    var imagesPath = settings.ImagesPath; //<--
}
```